# Multiple Partitions under /home and mount it as /home

Tags: 20.04

I Have 2 HD.  256 SSD and a 2TB HD.

/boot, /root, /var, /tmp and /usr loaded on the 256 GB SSD and /home in the 2TB HD.

I want to make multiple partitions like ~/documents, ~/work, ~/Music, ~/Movies and mount them as /home.  Is this possible and if possible how to do it?

Comment: you mean logical partitions under primary partition /home ? Why you need it as you have already shifted the partition to HDD from SSD.

Comment: Better not to have so many system partitions. I have ESP & / (root) on SSD and keep /home inside / but only the hidden . (hidden) user configuration files. I even move Thunderbird & Firefox to data partition. I then have very large data partition on HDD and link all folders back into /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315714
& 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198

Comment: Thanks guys.  If the HD fails, most of the files will get lost.  Partitioning it accordingly, there is a good possibility of retriewing most of the wanted work files.  That was the reason i asked.

Comment: I would not rely on partitioning to save your data in the event of a hard drive failure.  First, this would have no benefit whatsoever on a SSD.  If a HDD fails, it's really not going to make recovery any easier that you've partitioned the drive.  I fear that in the event of failure you will actually find that most or all of the files are not recoverable, and the ones that are will require significant technical expertise and a huge amount of wasted time and stress.  **Backups** to another device, and preferably another location, are the only reliable way to protect against data loss.